# How to get to the parent node of selected model that is being projected using ARKIT in swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have projected a model in sceneView using Arkit
when I tap the model the selected layer of that model is printed I want to get to the main parent node of all the layers of that model. here is my tap method where selected node of that model is printed.

```
 @objc func didTap(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation)
    guard let node = hitTestResults.first?.node else { return }
    print(node.name!)
}
```

Im new to this ignore my naming convections and help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`SCNNode` has a property called `parentNode`.

So you can simply go up to that, in if that is not the one you are searching for, simply go up to his `parentNode` etc...

Comment: yeah but when selected node's parent has also some has parent and so on. I want to get the main parent name which has all the childs.

Comment: So simply go up until there is no parent :)

Comment: what if there are 10-20 parents?